# Acquisition method of the file path in cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I'm just training cocos2dx.
There are some folders in Resource folder.
And there are some image in their some folders.
How should I acquire the path to the file in each folder.
By the way, different folders have the image of the same file name, too.

example)

```
Resource
  folder A
    image01.png
  folder B
    image01.png
```

Comment: fyi it's path, not pass

Comment: @LearnCocos2D, it is its not it's :D

Comment: "it is 'path'" not "its path" as in "his or her path" ;)

Comment: haha! just saw your edit .. all makes sense now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this Document
http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Multi_resolution_support. 
You have multiple folders to support Multi Resolution.
To access that you have to add folder paths in SearchPath.